# Compare two records based on date and return the latest record in cassandra

Tags: java, date, cassandra

I have a table in Cassandra and id and Date are Primary column and Clustering Column.
[image]

What I want is, i.e. latest records for every id based on Date.
I cannot create new table or view for this.

Thanks :)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Cassandra (starting with Cassandra 3.6 as per [CASSANDRA-7017](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7017)), there is support for clause `PER PARTITION LIMIT` that will return N records for every partition. In your case, you'll need to define sorting order for `date` field by descending order, and you'll able to write like this:

```
SELECT * from TABLE PER PARTITION LIMIT 1;
```